# How to literally display echo contents in php

Tags: php, string

I'm looking to literally display the contents of echo or print instead of PHP processing the HTML contained within.

For example, if I have the following:
`echo("<a href='$file'>$file</a> <br />\n");` the PHP parser will literally display all my files within a directory as links. What if I wanted to literally output the HTML tags without executing them so that  would be displayed as plain text?

Thanks.

Comment: PHP doesn't "execute" tags, your browser does. You're definitely missing something here, can you provide a snippet of code?

Comment: Please show us an example of the desired output.

Comment: `// print.
foreach($files as $file) {
        echo("<a href='$file'>$file</a><<br />\n");
  
}`

I want that the echo above to display the <a href> portion literally (meaning not actually creating links), while the file variable actually gets populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `echo`, use php function `htmlentities` inside a html `code` tag:

```
echo "<code>";
echo htmlentities("<a href='$file'>$file</a> <br />\n");
echo "</code>";
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

'<' = `&lt;`
'>' = `&gt;`

```
echo ("&lt;a href='$file'&gt;$file&lt;/a&gt; &lt;br /&gt;\n");
```

or...

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<a href='$file'>$file</a> <br />\n");
```

Comment: While this is a good effort it's not very modular should I want to display other characters. Htmlspecialchars or htmlentities is what I was looking for. Thanks.